# Pesquisar em todas as colunas de uma tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery, table

Estou usando a função a baixo pra fazer uma pesquisa "live" em uma tabela. O problema é que quero que ela traga dados em todas as colunas, e atualmente está trazendo apenas a primeira.

```
    function pesquisaTabela() {
      // Declare variables
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
      input = document.getElementById("search");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("dados");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      console.log("ssss"+tr.length);
      // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
          if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
            console.log(tr[i]);
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**Tabela**

```
        <table class"table-highlight" id="dados">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th data-field="id">Item</th>
                  <th data-field="numero">Número de Rastreamento</th>
                  <th data-field="data">Enviado em</th>
                  <th data-field="status">Status</th>

              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Pacote 01</td>
                <td><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#modal1">BR021WMR000016437462</a></td>
                <td>20/01/2017</td>
                <td><span>Em trânsito</span></td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Pacote 02</td>
                <td><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#modal1">SP021WMR000016437462</a></td>
                <td>15/01/2017</td>
                <td><span>Entregue</span></td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Pacote 03</td>
                <td><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#modal1">CR021WMR000016437462</a></td>
                <td>20/01/2017</td>
                <td><span>Cancelado</span></td>

              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Em vêz de fazer a procura só no primeiro `td` podes fazer no `tr` com todo o seu conteúdo.

Substitui

```
td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1
```

por

```
tr.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1
```

Podes simplificar o código ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o1462r79/)) mas o ideal seria ter em cache alguns elementos. A solução final poderia ser assim:

([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmvp7yx5/))

```js
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keyup', pesquisaTabela());

function pesquisaTabela() {
  var filter, table, tr, td, i;
  table = document.getElementById("dados");
  return function() {
    tr = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
    filter = this.value.toUpperCase();
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      var match = tr[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1;
      tr[i].style.display = match ? "block" : "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
tr {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="search">
</div>
<table class="table-highlight" id="dados">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id">Item</th>
      <th data-field="numero">Número de Rastreamento</th>
      <th data-field="data">Enviado em</th>
      <th data-field="status">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Pacote 01</td>
      <td><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#modal1">BR021WMR000016437462</a>
      </td>
      <td>20/01/2017</td>
      <td><span>Em trânsito</span>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pacote 02</td>
      <td><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#modal1">SP021WMR000016437462</a>
      </td>
      <td>15/01/2017</td>
      <td><span>Entregue</span>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pacote 03</td>
      <td><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#modal1">CR021WMR000016437462</a>
      </td>
      <td>20/01/2017</td>
      <td><span>Cancelado</span>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Nota:** se os `tr` forem estáticos essa linha pode parrar para fora da função interior, e ficar em cache como `table`, na linha abaixo de `table = document.getElementById("dados");`

Comment: perdão, mas dessa forma a busca não funcionou para nenhum campo.

Comment: @LucasTorres coloca o teu HTML com exemplo de texto na tabela e texto de procura, assim monto um exemplo e coloco aqui.

Comment: Ok. Adicionei o texto da tabela

Comment: @LucasTorres melhorei a resposta com o teu HTML.

Comment: deu certo, porém os estilos não se aplicaram. Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: @LucasTorres adapta o meu jsFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/kmvp7yx5/) com o teu CSS, senão é impossivel saber o que pode estar a falhar.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/torreslucas13/e60d22256a7300002bbc63fe360c7502  Esse é o codigo, após a busca, aparentemente a tabela perde as formatações. Não seria por conta do "block" e "none"

Comment: @LucasTorres usa `table-row` em vez de `block`. Parece ser esse o estilo inicial.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>
  <p style="text-align: right">
    <b>Digite o Nome do Produto:</b>
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Buscar">
  </p>
</div>
```

```js
$("#search").keyup(function() {
  var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

  $("table tr").each(function(index) {
    if (!index) return;
    $(this).find("td").each(function() {
      var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
      var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
      $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
      return not_found;
    });
  });
});
```